# not able to detect mongodb shutdown

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My code:

```
  db = mongoose.connect(
    config[MONGO_HOST_CONF],
    config[MONGO_ACCOUNTS_DB_CONF],
    config[MONGO_PORT_CONF]
    }
  );

  db.connection.on('opening', function() {
    console.log("connecting");
  });

  db.connection.on('open', function() {
    console.log("connected");
  });

  db.connection.on('error', function() {
    console.log("disconnected");
  });
  db.connection.on('close', function() {
    console.log("disconnected");
  });
```

When I start my webserver which then opens a connection to mongodb, I can see "connected" in logs.

But when I do a mongodb stop, I dont see "disconnected" in logs. Neither do I see "connecting".

I am trying to detect if for some reason mongodb went down. Then reconnect before bailing out.

What is wrong above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`opening` isn't an event [that is sent by Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection), try `connecting` instead.

Also, `close` is an event that will be called when the *client* is closing the connection; in the situation where the server has stopped (or crashed), it isn't sent. Try using the `disconnected` event for that.

Comment: I tried connected, disconnected, error, close...nothing seems to be emitted when I shutdown my mongoDB....only connection.on('open') works when I first try to establish the connection. I think disconneced/close are emitted when client (in this case me) initiates the disconnect.

Comment: @user2384694 strange, it works for me (`disconnect` event is generated when MongoDB is shut down). [This is what I tested with](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/c1ab85e3669c3b0a6f0f).

Comment: which version of mongoose/mongodb are you using? I use mongoos 2.3.13. thanks for helping me out!. With your exact code, I dont see connected and disconnected however I do see "open" being emitted

Comment: Ok with upgrading mongoose, I was able to catch events. thx a lot...although unrelated but if could comment if I can SAFELY upgrade from 2.3.13 ----> 3.6.15 (mongoose) in production?

Comment: nope, there are lots of changes between mongoose 2.x and 3.x. [See here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/migration.html) for guidance